# concatenate only unique values

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have this function

```
Public Function CONCATENATESPECIAL(rng As Range) As String
Dim rng1 As Range

CONCATENATESPECIAL = ""

For Each rng1 In rng
    If (Not Rows(rng1.Row).Hidden) And (rng1.Value <> "") Then
    CONCATENATESPECIAL = CONCATENATESPECIAL & rng1.Text & "|"
    End If
Next rng1

End Function
```

It basically concatenate values in some range with "|".

What I need is - is it possible to edit it, to - if there are, in that range some duplicate values, to include it only once? To sum up - concatenate only unique values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps use `INSTR()` to check if the `.value` is already in `CONCATENATESPECIAL` before adding it?

Comment: @BruceWayne one issue I see with this is data could be a substring of other data and still be unique.  An alternative would be saving to an array [filtering that for unique values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017852/vba-get-unique-values-from-array) and joining after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would likely go about it this way. I would add everything to a collection, and set the key equal to the range value. The `on error resume next` bit will stop it from erroring when it attempts to put a duplicate in the collection. I would need a bit more validation, but for the most part it should suffice.

```
Public Function concatenatespecial(rng As Range) As String

Dim col As New Collection
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim str As String
Dim itm As Variant

On Error Resume Next
For Each rng1 In rng
    If rng1 <> "" Then
        col.Add rng1.Value, rng1.Value
    End If
Next rng1
On Error GoTo 0

For Each itm In col
    str = str & "|" & itm
Next itm

concatenatespecial = str

End Function
```

Comment: [Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb7y698k(v=vs.90).aspx).Add requires only one argument.  Also letting unmanaged (`Resume Next`) errors controlling your code is a bad practice,  and I think it won't work if you have more than one duplicates.  Please test your code before posting it as an answer.

Comment: It looks like its working. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, it is true that Collection.Add only requires one argument, but I am leveraging the fact that the optional Key argument must be unique. And, while I agree it is bad to let unmanaged `Resume Next` errors control your code, the alternative here is cycling through the collection to check each time. To mitigate the risk, I have removed all code except what is necessary to populate the collection, from the `Resume Next` block. I am also unclear why you think this would fail with multiple duplicates. My testing showed this to work even in that scenario.

Comment: Use dictionary instead of collection then no need for resume next http://stackoverflow.com/a/915333